# Solving Ordinary Differential Equation: $\;(x^2+y^2) \, dx+3xy \, dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the following differential equation?

$$(x^2+y^2) \, dx+3xy \, dy=0$$

Comment: The solution manual lists, as a solution:
[(x^2+4y^2)^3]x^2=C

Comment: When I worked it out by two different methods, I obtained two solutions. I have just begun reviewing differential equations and lack the intuition to identify incorrect solutions. My "answers" are listed as follows and both methods involved an integrating factor:
1) y(x)=+/-0.5*sqrt[-x^2+Cx^(-2/3)]
2) C=(3/8)x^8/3+(3/2)x^(2/3)y^2

Answer (score 2):

This equation is homogeneous. So, having entered a new value $t=x/y$ or $t=y/x$ and having evalueted derivatives, you can get an equation with shared variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternately use Bernoulli DE form. [image]